# Blazor Server в связке с jquery и фильтры Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor

В приложении Blazor подключил библиотеку Isotope, которая в свою очередь обращается к элементам DOM по средствам jquery.
Фильтры Isotope работают только в том случае, если страница на которой они расположены загрузилась первой, а в случае перехода на нее с другой страницы - фильтры Isotope перестают работать (чтоб фильтры снова заработали нужно перезагрузить страницу).

Всё что удалось выяснить, это как будто jquery не видит DOM-элементы - jquery перестает отлавливать события on('click', function () и не находит элементы по селекторам. Если повесить на кнопки onclick="Func(this)" - то одна проблема решается, а решить вопрос с поиском в документе нужных элементов для фильтрации не удается.

Подозреваю что при переходе по страницам Blazor нужно каким то образом каждый раз инициализировать DOM - вопрос, как это правильно делать?

На сайте используется owlCarousel и другие библиотеки и таких проблем не возникает.

Если через событие
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
динамически добавлять файл js с со следующим кодом:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Isotope filter
    var portfolioIsotope = $('.isotope-container').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });
    $('#isotope-flters li button').on('click', function () {
        $("#isotope-flters li button").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        //alert(this);
        portfolioIsotope.isotope({ filter: $(this).data('filter') });
    });
});
```

тогда всё работает исправно, не считая что при каждом переходе добавляется файл js.

Comment: Тут нашел вполне рабочее решение: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003275/blazor-server-app-document-ready-equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003275/blazor-server-app-document-ready-equivalent)